# In what countries is Christianity banned?

Tags: history

I am doing a history day project and ours is on the rights and responsibilities and we wanted to know in what countries is Christianity banned and for what reason.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this question is really a good fit for this site.  It's an interesting question, to be sure, but doesn't really fit our format.  For one,the answer is likely to change, and fr another, there's the question of where to draw the line. Do we include countries where Christianity isn't banned, but owning a Bible is? Or where it's illegal to convert from Islam, or to evangelize but not illegal to simply be Christian? It's just too broad and non-specific.  This needs more focus to be a good question.

Comment: **China, Myanmar and any Muslim countries**. But this is actually a "list question". If you'r lucky, someone might make the complete list for you.

Comment: Since this is indeed a *dynamic list*, I suggest you look at [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Christians#Current_situation_.281989_to_present.29). More details can be found on [this Open Doors page](http://www.opendoorsuk.org/resources/country_profiles.php).

Comment: It is also worth noting that in the more liberal western align muslim countries like the UAE there are churches to which you can go and worship but the attempt to convert muslims is still prohibited. Making them not entirely religiously free.

Comment: I bet there's a complete list online somewhere. Did you try Google?

Comment: So you're asking us to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 2):

There's a list by WWL
http://www.worldwatchlist.us/world-watch-list-countries/

Extreme persecution:

North Korea
Saudi Arabia
Afghanistan
Iraq
Somalia
Maldives
Mali
Iran
Yemen
Eritrea
Syria
Sudan
Nigeria